# wp query template tags not working

Tags: wp-query

I create a page : contact-us then I specify a template for this page and this is the template code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Template wp_query
*/
?>

 <?php  
   $arg = array (
      'post_type' => 'post',
       'post_per_page' => -1 ,

     );

     $test = new WP_Query($arg);
     var_dump($test);

     if ($test->have_posts()) {
       while ($test-> have_posts()) : $test-> the_post();

              echo   $test->get_the_title();
               echo  $test->get_the_content;

         endwhile;
         }
         wp_reset_query();
          ?>
```

the result page is blanck even if the var_dump($test) return the list of post with the information.   for your information i tried query_post() and it works fine.
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template tags are not methods of `WP_Query` object. They are functions.

On the other hand `have_posts` and `the_post` are methods of `WP_Query`.

So in your code you should use:

```
while ($test->have_posts()) : $test->the_post();
```

as you do, but then:

```
           echo  get_the_title();
           echo  get_the_content();
```

Also... if you want to echo these values, it would be much better to use `the_title` and `the_content` instead - there are some additional filters and actions fired up.